# ModelBase object is not iterable error

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm attempting to create a form which creates appointments for people. It will populate a selection box by taking data from a database.

The models.py:

```
class customer(models.Model):
    # Need autoincrement, unique and primary
    cstid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    age=models.IntegerField()
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class doctor(models.Model):
    docid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True) # Need autoincrement, unique and primary
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    regid = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="", blank=True)
    photo = models.CharField(
        max_length=35, default="", blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(default="", blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    qualifications = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, default="", blank=True)
    about = models.CharField(
        max_length=35, default="", blank=True)
    specialities = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, default="", blank=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="ENT", blank=True)
    fees = models.FloatField(default=300.0)
    displayfee = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    slotrange = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    slotdurn = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    breakrange = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, default="", blank=True)
    slotsleft = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, default="", blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class appointment(models.Model):
    # Need autoincrement, unique and primary
    appid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=1)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    time = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now)
    docid = models.ForeignKey(doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    cstid = models.ForeignKey(customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

The form - forms.py:

```
class AddAppointmentForm(forms.Form):
    docchoices = []
    for doc in doctor:
        docst = [doc.docid, doc.name]
        docchoices.append(docst)
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100)
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        choices=docchoices,
    )
    age = forms.IntegerField(max_value=100,min_value=1, required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Phone', max_length=14)
    email = forms.CharField(label='Email', max_length=25)
    address = forms.Textarea()
    city = forms.CharField(label='Email', max_length=20)
    doctors = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Select,
        choices=docchoices,
    )
```

Relevant part of views.py:

```
def get_createappointmentform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddAppointmentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('appointments/addapp.html')
    else:
        form = AddAppointmentForm()
    return render(request, 'appointments/name.html', {'form': form})
```

The template - name.html

```
<form action="/addapp.html" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When I try to load the page http://127.0.0.1:8000/appointments/getappointment, it doesnt load. Command line shows this:

```
File "/home/joel/myappointments/appointments/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
File "/home/joel/myappointments/appointments/views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .forms import NameForm
File "/home/joel/myappointments/appointments/forms.py", line 7, in <module>
    class AddAppointmentForm(forms.Form):
File "/home/joel/myappointments/appointments/forms.py", line 9, in AddAppointmentForm
    for doc in doctor:
TypeError: 'ModelBase' object is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The culprit is `for doc in doctor:`, the `doctor` is the `doctor` model, and that class is not iterable. Furthermore writing `for` loops in a `class` is not forbidden, but rather strange (and probably an anti-pattern).

Comment: Furthermore it is very strange that you then assign these choices to the `gender` field. As far as I know, a `doctor` is not a gender.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That was an intended error. :)